# org.json.JSONException android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am getting jsonarray i have done jsonarray request through volley below is the url of to check json.
 Problem is this i am not getting response.

```
String url="http://reesguru.com/DesktopModules/ReEsServer/API/PropertyWebService/GetDataForSearchBySaleProperty?location=&propertyFor=1&propertyType=0&bathroom=0&bedroom=0&minprice=0&maxprice=0&mincoverarea=0&maxcoverarea=0&minplotarea=0&maxplotarea=0&Possession=0&TransactionType=0&orderby=UsdMonthlyRent&orderto=Desc";

        JsonArrayRequest request=new JsonArrayRequest(url,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {


                Log.e("response",String.valueOf(response));
                for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++)
                {
                     JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        String title = obj.getString("Title");
                        Log.e("title", String.valueOf(title));
                }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("e", e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        },new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("error",e.getMessage());
            }
        });
queue.add(request);
```

}
Thanyou in advance.

This my exception.i am getting half response in exception

```
org.json.JSONException: Value[{"ProjectID":12,"ProjectseId":"Pr5735385","AgentId":33,"UserId":10,"Title":"Sunshine","Description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi …","Url":"www.vapiview.com","ProjectFor":1,"ProjectType":4,"ViewType":"0","FloorNumber":null,"TotalFloor":null,"ProjectSubType":41,"KeyLandmark":"MadhuBan Dem","LandArea":null,"LandAreaUnit":null,"Possession":null,"TransactionType":null,"NoofBedrooms":null,"NoofBathrooms":null,"NoofKitchen":null,"NoofBalcony":null,"FaceView":null,"ProjectAge":1,"Location":"Vapi","City":"Vapi","Postcode":"WC1B 4BB","ProjectOwnership":null,"DistanceDetails":"RailwayStation:12.00","SalePrice":0.00,"Furnished":null,"HomeFeaturesList":"","SocietyFeaturesList":"","OtherFeaturesList":"","Latitude":20.000000000000000,"Longitude":20.000000000000000,"ZoomValue":3,"IsDeleted":false,"upsize_ts":"AAAAAAAA8ho=","currencyunit":"","UsdSalePrice":0.00,"BuiltArea":null,"BuiltAreaUnit":null,"Project_QRCode":null,"GeoLocation_QRCode":null,"KeyName":"Commercial","ProjectImage":"/DesktopModules/ReEsWeb/Images/Property-Images/crop_20140603154802.jpg"},{"ProjectID":13,"ProjectseId":"Pr5735385","AgentId":33,"UserId":10,"Title":"Sunshine","Description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi …","Url":"www.vapiview.com","ProjectFor":1,"ProjectType":3,"ViewType":"0","FloorNumber":null,"TotalFloor":null,"ProjectSubType":37,"KeyLandmark":"MadhuBan Dem","LandArea":null,"LandAreaUnit":null,"Possession":null,"TransactionType":null,"NoofBedrooms":null,"NoofBathrooms":null,"NoofKitchen":null,"NoofBalcony":null,"FaceView":null,"ProjectAge":1,"Location":"Vapi","City":"Vapi","Postcode":"WC1B 4BB","ProjectOwnership":null,"DistanceDetails":null,"SalePrice":0.00,"Furnished":null,"HomeFeaturesList":null,"SocietyFeaturesList":null,"OtherFeaturesList":null,"Latitude":21.190109900000000,"Longitude":72.813936900000040,"ZoomValue":8,"IsDeleted":false,"upsize_ts":"AAAAAAAA8hs=","currencyunit":"","UsdSalePrice":0.00,"BuiltArea":null,"BuiltAreaUnit":null,"Project_QRCode":"/DesktopModules/ReEsWeb/Images/QRCodeImages/ProjectQRCode/13ProjectQRCode.jpg","GeoLocation_QRCode":"/DesktopModules/ReEsWeb/Images/QRCode_GeoLocationImages/ProjectGeoLocationImages/13GeoLocationQRCode.jpg","KeyName":"Residential","ProjectImage":null},{"ProjectID":14,"ProjectseId":"Pr5735385","AgentId":33,"UserId":10,"Title":"Sunshine","Description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi …","Url":"www.vapiview.com","ProjectFor":1,"ProjectType":4,"ViewType":"0","FloorNumber":0,"TotalFloor":0,"ProjectSubType":41,"KeyLandmark":"MadhuBan Dem","LandArea":0.0,"LandAreaUnit":"0","Possession":"1","TransactionType":0,"NoofBedrooms":1,"NoofBathrooms":1,"NoofKitchen":1,"NoofBalcony":1,"FaceView":"0","ProjectAge":1,"Location":"Vapi","City":"Vapi","Postcode":"WC1B 4BB","ProjectOwnership":null,"DistanceDetails":"","SalePrice":0.00,"Furnished":"Fully","HomeFeaturesList":null,"SocietyFeaturesList":null,"OtherFeaturesList":null,"Latitude":0.000000000000000,"Longitude":0.000000000000000,"ZoomValue":0,"IsDeleted":false,"upsize_ts":"AAAAAAAA8hw=","currencyunit":"","UsdSalePrice":0.00,"BuiltArea":0.0,"BuiltAreaUnit":"","Project_QRCode":null,"GeoLocation_QRCode":null,"KeyName":"Commercial","ProjectImage":null},{"ProjectID":15,"ProjectseId":"Pr5735385","AgentId":33,"UserId":10,"Title":"TestProject","Description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi …","Url":"www.google.com","ProjectFor":1,"ProjectType":3,"ViewType"
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
```

Comment: check you json it reutrn extra comma,,after project id

Comment: @Tufan but http://jsonlint.com/ says its a valid JSON response

Comment: sorry its my mistake wait ..i will tell you soln...can you post you logcat

Comment: its valid json response

Comment: try @apk's solution then check your logcat. See both are same or not.

Comment: i have posted my logcat exception

Comment: @payaltuteja I guess you are not getting inside `onResponse(JSONArray response)` right instead into `onErrorResponse`?

Comment: @payal edited answer try it instead of getString use getInt

Comment: i have used getInt but not getting inside onResponse(JSONArray response)

Comment: You are saying right @Mithun

Answer (score 1):

Okay! If I try with Rest URL provided in your code snippet, I am getting `ParseError` like this:

[image]

So pinpoint the issue I tried several things, and ultimately took your response and created a public gist [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/roymithun/196cb432e9c78f727843/raw/ba70eeb43012dfe5067cef91c72a73c00c61a121/myjson1) with same response you are getting from your web service URL and then I am not getting any error.

The difference I could point out is some special characters inside your "description" tag.

In gist I created it appears as nisi `Ã¢â‚¬Â¦`
If you open your response in Chrome it appears as `nisi â€¦`
While debugging in eclipse it appears as `nisi …`

There is definitely some encoding issue with your WS response. If you could somehow make some tweaks to those characters you can make it working.

**Update:**
I tried your request now in `AdvancedRestClient` (you can add this app to your chrome browser) and found that your response is with `""` where all your response is embedded between **"**{your_json_object}**"** and as such it can't be parsed by `Volley` APIs.

[image]

If you are wandering how would a valid `JSON` response look like, try with http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json

It ideally should look like below:

[image]

So back to your WS only :) Let me know how it goes!

Comment: I have made some changes in WS. Now these "nisi â€¦" character are removed i have edit the url.Still not working

Comment: Ok @payaltuteja I finally found the issue... Sadly, Its your response only... See my edit to the answer...

Comment: @MithunThankyou very much for telling me error.. i will  tweak it and try again

Comment: Cool... please try sending request using `AdvancedRestClient` and see the response structure is proper or not

Answer (score 0):

There's no "PropertyID" in response of this url:

```
String url="http://reesguru.com/DesktopModules/ReesServer/API/PropertyWebService/GetDataForSearchByProject?location=&ProjectFor=1&projectType=0&bathroom=0&bedroom=0&minprice=0&maxprice=0&mincoverarea=0&maxcoverarea=0&minplotarea=0&maxplotarea=0&Possession=0&TransactionType=0&orderby=UsdSalePrice&orderto=Desc&currencyto=";
```

And if you need "ProjectID" instead, as 'apk' answered, notice that it's not String, it's int.

```
String name = String.valueOf(obj.getInt("ProjectID"));
```

Comment: Also, if you want to convert int to String, use String.valueOf();

Comment: @payal tuteja   int name = obj.getInt("PropertyID");  change to ProjectID

Comment: @Artem_Iens i have edited my ans.Problem is same now tell the solution please

Answer (score -1):

isuue is this line String name = obj.getString("PropertyID"); it should be

```
String name = obj.getInt("ProjectID");
```